# Display field from database from a unique html id

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I've got a PHP Laravel project in which I'm getting some IDs from a database.  I would like to click on these dynamic IDs and display dynamic content coming from the database.  The html looks like so:

```
    <div class="details" id="plusBtn-{{$ticket->id}}">
       Click Icon
    </div>
```

The ID for the element above would be plusBtn-1, plusBtn-2, etc, which comes from the database...  When the user clicks on the "Click icon", the front end should display the following coming from the database:

```
    <div class="ticketDetail">
       <p>Contact: {{$ticket->tel}}</p>
       {{$ticket->description}}
    </div>
```

The Javascript so far, consoles out the ID of .details whenever you click on the "Click icon" :

```
$(".details[id]").each(function() {
        let plusBtnArr = [];
        plusBtnArr.push(this);
        for (let i = 0; i < plusBtnArr.length; i++) {
            var elementId = plusBtnArr;
            $(elementId).click(() => {
                console.log(elementId);
            });
        }
    });
```

I don't mean to waste any one's time as I'm sure a question similar to mine has probably been posted in the history of the internet.  I have been trying for three days and can't find a way to do this.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution seems to render the details of all the tickets beforehand.
Let's inspect this piece of code:

```
<div class="ticketDetail hidden" id="ticketDetail-{{$ticket->id}}">
  <p>Contact: {{$ticket->tel}}</p>
  {{$ticket->description}}
</div>
```

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Now we have the details of a ticket with the id attached. Render the details of all of the tickets in the DOM tree.

When clicking on the icon, we need to somehow get the id of the ticket. I would advise to attach it separately:

```
<div class="details" id="plusBtn-{{$ticket->id}}" data-ticketId="{{$ticket->id}}">
  Click Icon
</div>
```

Now we can use it to find a proper ticket:

```
const element = $(elementId);
element.click(() => {
  const ticketId = element.attr('data-ticketId');
  const ticketDetail = $(`#ticketDetail-${ticketId}`);
  ticketDetail.removeClass('hidden');
});
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: This is perfect, I really appreciate your help Marcin!